# Java 8 Time with variable day

Tags: java, java-8

I can't seem to get my date with variable whitespace to parse.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss yyyy");
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(date, formatter);
```

This is the format I have to accept

```
Sat Jul  2 08:52:13 2016
Sat Jul 12 08:52:13 2016
```

I can get the top to pass if I change my formatter to the below, but it will break with a 2 digit number

```
EEE MMM  d HH:mm:ss yyyy
```

Comment: This is an option: [Eliminating the subtle whitespace handling difference between DateTimeFormat and Joda's DateTimeFormatter](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19439821)

Comment: That's a good idea. I had hoped their would be an official answer, but it's a simple edit. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try pattern of "EEE MMM ppd HH:mm:ss yyyy" for your format.

`ppd` outputs the day padded on the left with spaces to a width of 2.

See Pad modifier in [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) for more details.

Comment: This works great and seems to be a really clean solution compared to formatting the string before formatting the string like the replaceAll() answer  requires.